# React project not loading after npm install and npm start

Tags: reactjs, git, npm

I cloned this git repository -> `https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component`

I'm fairly new to react. I tried starting this project by `npm install` and `npm start` as I was suggested but it shows me this error message.

```
rollup v2.7.2

bundles ./src/index.js → dist\react-data-table-component.dev.js...

created dist\react-data-table-component.dev.js in 16.4s

[2020-05-01 13:45:31] waiting for changes...
```

And it keeps waiting. I googled a lot for it but didn't find a way to make this repository run on my system. Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If suspect that you are trying to use this data table package.
If you are trying to install this package, you have to do following.

1. Create react app using `npx create-react-app projectName`
2. Then install this particular package [NPM LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component)
   `npm i react-data-table-component`
3. Then use this package in your code according to document.

```js
import React from 'react';
import DataTable, { createTheme } from 'react-data-table-component';

createTheme('solarized', {
  text: {
    primary: '#268bd2',
    secondary: '#2aa198',
  },
  background: {
    default: '#002b36',
  },
  context: {
    background: '#cb4b16',
    text: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  divider: {
    default: '#073642',
  },
  action: {
    button: 'rgba(0,0,0,.54)',
    hover: 'rgba(0,0,0,.08)',
    disabled: 'rgba(0,0,0,.12)',
  },
});

const App = () => (
  <DataTable
    title="Arnold Movies"
    columns={columns}
    theme="solarized"
  />
);

export default App;
```

Comment: I want to use this code ->
https://jbetancur.github.io/react-data-table-component/?path=/story/expandable-rows--custom-expanded-component
How can I use this code from the package? It asks for the data files like '../constants/sampleRMEpisodes' and '../../../src/index' if I directly copy paste. 
Is there any way I can run this as a project in my local machine?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. You can follow those steps. Create your own react project and install this datatable package using npm. Then you can replace app.js code with example code.

Comment: First it says 
./src/App.js
  Line 26:61:  'columns' is not defined  no-undef

And if I give array of data to column to at least run it with  then it says ->
There are no records to display